# How to make each of div or article fit the screen fullly

Tags: html, css, fullscreen

```
<body>
    <article id="one">...</article>
    <article id="two">...</article>
    <article id="three">...</article>
    ...
</body>
```

How can I make each of article fit to the entire screen resolution? For example, the initial page is the content of article#one, and when you scroll down, the next page is article#two.

I really need this.
Thanks.

Comment: you are using article outside of section? I have always wandered, the sections are sections of text or sections of the website itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple:

```
article { height:100%; }
```

Also, make sure `html` and `body` have `height:100%;` as well.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dvjTf/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I forgot to make html's height 100%